# UDPSocket (Ruby) - specifiy / capture local / sending port

Tags: ruby, sockets, udp, port

I want to send a packet to a host using UDPSocket (Ruby) specifying the port for the reciever.

Can I specify / capture the local port I am sending on? I have looked on https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/UDPSocket.html and whilst I can specify the port I am connecting to the host on, I cannot see any options / methods for the local port I am sending from.

I wonder if the socket that UDPSocket uses has access to the local port?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/IPSocket.html (super class of UDPSocket) I can see that the local outbound port is available from the addr method of the socket.

Regards